# Using variable vectors to rename a data frame

Tags: r, variables, character

So I have the following vector:

```
name <- c(5, 10, 12, 13, 24)
```

and I want to use it to rename my dataframe:

```
FINAL <- data.frame("Group" = GROUP_vector, 
                "min_name[1]" = min_1, 
                "min_name[2]" = min_2,
                "min_name[3]" = min_3, 
                "min_name[4]" = min_4,
                "min_name[5]" = min_5)
```

Of course I get this as a result:

```
Group min_name.1. min_name.2. min_name.3. min_name.4. min_name.5.
1      1         150          90         116         152         182
2      2         164          96         122         154         203
3      3         171          95         125         155         202
4      4         169          98         131         154         203
5      5         162          79         101         160         191
6      6         169          97         128         156         204
7      7         167          95         125         156         204
```

But I need this:

```
Group min_5 min_10 min_12 min_13 min_24
```

Is there any quick solution?

Comment: Use `setNames(out, c("Group", paste0("min_", name)))`

Comment: What code are you using to `rename`??

Comment: I am sorry I was not very precise: I wasn't renaming a data frame I was creating it! Is there a way to do this by creating the data frame?

Comment: Create it, then rename. What's wrong with that?

Comment: If you really want it all at once, `as.data.frame(setNames(list(GROUP_vector, min_1, min_2, ..., min_5), c("Group", paste0("min_", name))))` will work. But create it and then set names seems much more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this any good to you?

```
name <- c(5, 10, 12, 13, 24)
name2 <- paste("min_",name,sep="")
var1<-c(1,2)
var2<-c(2,3)
var3<-c(3,4)
var4<-c(4,5)
var5<-c(5,6)
df <- data.frame(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5)
colnames(df) <- name2
```